# Apagar arquivos automaticos

Tags: php

Bom galera, eu tenho um sistema, onde praticamente diariamente são enviados via uploads arquivos em pdf. Após um tempo fica com muito arquivo acumulado.

Por exemplo: Upo 100 arquivos pdf hj, amanha já coloco 20. Sendo assim, a partir do dia que upei os 100 arquivos pdfs, após 3 meses apaga esses 100.. no dia seguinte o mesmo esquema e apaga os 20 e assim sucessivamente, mas não se apaga tudo de uma vez.

Alguma ideia ou ajuda?

Obrigado desde já!

Eu tenho essa programação em PHP abaixo,

```
    <?php
  $dateFormat = "d-m-Y H:i:s";
  $dir = 'uploads/*/*';

  if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
    if($objs == glob($dir)) {
    foreach($objs as $obj) {
      if (is_dir($obj)) continue; // Verifica se o arquivo é um diretório, se for, tudo que está abaixo é desconsiderado

      $dateFile = strtotime(date($dateFormat, filemtime($obj))); // Data da última modificação do arquivo convertida em time;
      $dateToRemove = strtotime(date($dateFormat, filemtime($obj) + (60 * 5))); // Tempo da última modificação + 3 meses convertida em time;
      if($dateFile >= $dateToRemove) unlink($obj); // Exclui o arquivo se este possuir 03 meses desde a última modificação
    }
}
}
?>
```

Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" name="excluir" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja apagar todos os Boletos?                         ATENÇÃO! ESSA AÇÃO NÃO TERÁ VOLTA!')" >APAGAR TODOS OS BOLETOS</button>
```

EDIT: Código editado conforme as explicações.
Fiz testes com 1 minuto, upei arquivos, esperei 1 minuto.. upei mais alguns, fui excluir e excluiu todos.

Comment: Utilize a função [`filemtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filemtime.php) para capturar a data da última modificação do arquivo. Essa função retornará o tempo no padrão *unix timestamp*; feito isso, basta comparar o intervalo de tempo com a função `date` ou `DateTime::diff`

Comment: Teria algum exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! Notei que há um **erro** de sintáxe em seu código:

> if($objs = glob($dir)){

**O correto:**

```
if($objs == glob($dir)){
```

Ao meu ver, a explicação do seu problema não ficou muito clara. Poderia dar mais detalhes do seu problema?

@EDIT - 28/05

A partir da resposta do Keven Carneiro adaptei o script de forma que acredito que irá solucionar o seu problema.

```
$dateFormat = "d-m-Y";
$dir = 'uploads/*/*';

if($objs == glob($dir)) {
    foreach($objs as $obj) {
      if (is_dir($obj)) continue; // Verifica se o arquivo é um diretório, se for, tudo que está abaixo é desconsiderado

      $dateFile = strtotime(date($dateFormat, filemtime($obj))); // Data da última modificação do arquivo convertida em time;
      $dateToRemove = strtotime(date($dateFormat, filemtime($obj) + (3600 * 24 * 90))); // Tempo da última modificação + 3 meses convertida em time;
      if(time() >= $dateToRemove) unlink($obj); // Exclui o arquivo se este possuir 03 meses desde a última modificação
    }
}
```

Caso você queira testar a diferença em horas você deverá:

1. Mudar o "$dateFormat" para "d-m-Y H:i:s";
2. Mudar a linha seguinte alterando o tempo de soma para, por exemplo, 3600 apenas. (Valor de uma hora)

> $dateToRemove = strtotime(date($dateFormat, filemtime($obj) + (3600 *
>   24 * 90)));

Certifique-se de conferir se o valor que está sendo recebido em $objs é válido para entrar na primeira condição:

> if($objs == glob($dir)) {

Tentei explicar ao máximo o que cada função faz, mas você pode tirar dúvidas aqui ou consultar a documentação! **Espero ter ajudado.**

Comment: Vou tentar ser mais claro,
A cada dia é upados vários pdfs. Hoje eu upo 100 pdfs, amanhã eu upo 20 pdf.
Passados 3 meses, a exclusão é automatica pra esses 100 pdfs, no dia seguinte é a mesma coisa para os 20 pdfs e assim sucessivamente.

Alguma forma ou solução? agradeço pela correção!

Comment: Comparação, o arquivo não apaga :(

Comment: Verifique se a partir da edição da minha resposta você consegue obter êxito.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente! Pra alterar por 5 minutos: (3600 * 24 * 90))); e fazer testes. 3600 seria segundos? 24 seria 1 dia? e 90 dias/3 meses, correto? em 5 minutos seria como?

Comment: 3600 é o valor referente a uma hora em segundos. Caso você queira testar 05 minutos, basta converter o valor de 05 minutos em segundos, 60 * 5, que daria 300 segundos.

Comment: Posso estar sendo muito persistente, desculpe. Poderia verificar o código pra mim e ver se está certo? fiz teste e não funcionou ainda. Editei la em cima

Comment: Olá, editei um trecho do código e está funcionando. Copie o código inteiramente e substitua o que está utilizando. Note que se você estiver copiando um arquivo para a pasta, a data de sua última modificação não será a data da cópia. Para evitar isso, lembre-se de criar novos arquivos.

Comment: Funciona somente em localhost ou hospedagem(linux) tbm funciona?

Comment: Funciona em qualquer ambiente. Lembre-se que você pode fazer o debug passo a passo e ver os valores que estão sendo recebidos a fim de solucionar o problema. Por exemplo, você poderia apagar a função unlink() e verificar se a condição está caindo nesse ponto, e por qual motivo.

Comment: Eu tenho algumas pastas após o uploads, exemplo: uploads/a1 , uploads/a2 e os arquivos estão dentro delas. Vou tentar testar tudo hoje a noite. O * atende e entende como somente tem arquivos nessas pastas a1, a2?

Comment: glob("uploads/*/*") retornará um array com todos os arquivos de todas as pastas dentro de uploads.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer um script em PHP que leia a data de criação de um arquivo para removê-lo usando a função `filectime`:

```php
$dateFormat = "Y-m-d"; // Altere para "Y-m-d H:i:s" se quiser levar em consideração os segundos.
$dateToRemove = date($dateFormat, strtotime("-3 months"));
$dir = 'uploads/*/*';

if($objs = glob($dir)) {
    foreach($objs as $obj) {
      if (is_dir($obj)) continue;
      if (date($dateFormat, filectime($obj)) > $dateToRemove) continue;
      unlink($obj);
    }
}
```

Você pode salvar este código em um arquivo .php e executá-lo de tempos em tempos. Para não ter que executar manualmente, você pode usar uma ferramenta que execute scripts agendados em intervalos de tempo definidos por você, no Linux scripts desse tipo são conhecidos como CRON e no Windows essa funcionalidade é conhecida como Tarefas Agendadas, disponível através do Agendador de Tarefas.

Você pode configurá-lo manualmente ou usar um serviço on-line como o https://cron-job.org, que vai chamar sua página PHP com a frequência que você definir.

Para mais detalhes sobre a função `filectime` você pode consultar a documentação do PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filectime.php

---

PS: Você pode ter estranhado a minha forma de escrever código `if (condicaoFalsa) continue`, mas é uma técnica utilizada para aumentar a manutenibilidade de código.

Você pode ver um exemplo disso aqui (em inglês): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements

Comment: Entendi, muito bom! Como faço pra testar se está funcionando "pra não ter que esperar 3 meses", mas a partir do meu submit, fazer um teste por minuto, por exemplo?

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste criando um arquivo de teste, trocando o parâmetro `"-3 months"` por `"-1 minute"` e rodar o script um minuto depois de ter criado o arquivo.

Comment: Estranhamente, eu faço pra testar com um minuto. Upo o arquivo, espero um minutos, upo novamente um e quando dou o submit, ele apaga os 2. :(

Comment: Você pode dar um `echo(date($dateFormat, filectime($obj))` para verificar como este valor está sendo computado. A causa mais provável é que como o formato de data está apenas dia, mês e ano, ele leva em consideração apenas o dia, fazendo com que todos os arquivos sejam excluídos. Você pode testar substituindo o `$dateFormat`pelo valor `Y-m-d H:i:s`, que levará em consideração também os segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui para funcionar eu mudei o formato da data para : `$dateFormat = "Y-m-d";`